# Linked list implementation for a QUEUE

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, queue, pseudocode

Here is my implementation for a queue using doubly linked list:

```
QUEUE-EMPTY
if L.head == NIL
    return True
else return False

QUEUE(x):
if L.head == NIL:
    x.prev = NIL
    L.head = x
else
    cur = L.head
    while cur.next != NIL
        cur = cur.next
    cur.next = x
    x.prev = cur
    x.next = NIL

DEQUEUE():
x = L.head
L.head = x.next
x.next.prev = L.head
return x
```

How to improve ? Is that correct ?

Is there a mean to make QUEUE O(1) ?

thanks !!

Comment: Doesn't sound like a question for [so]. Maybe sounds like a question for [codereview.se]. Also, what operations do you want to be O(1)? Queue are as fast as they are, when you want certain operations to be faster than they are, you'll probably need another data structure.

Comment: What happens with your queue when you dequeue an empty queue ? What would be the complexity of QUEUE if you keep a pointer to the last node of the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See changes + comments below:

```
QUEUE(x):
if L.head == NIL:
    x.prev = x.next = NIL // otherwise you never set up next
    L.head = x
else
    cur = L.head
    while cur.next != NIL
        cur = cur.next
    cur.next = x
    x.prev = cur
    x.next = NIL

DEQUEUE():
// handle empty queue
if L.head == NIL:
    ERROR! // or something
else
    x = L.head
    L.head = x.next
    if x.next != NIL: // handle empty queue
        x.next.prev = L.head NIL // otherwise it points to itself
    return x
```

**To make `QUEUE(x)` O(1), you need to keep a pointer to the tail.**

```
QUEUE(x):
if L.head == NIL:
    x.prev = NIL
    L.head = L.tail = x
else
    cur = L.tail
    cur.next = L.tail = x
    x.prev = cur
    x.next = NIL

DEQUEUE():
if L.head == NIL:
    ERROR! // or something
else
    x = L.head
    L.head = x.next
    if x.next != NIL:
        x.next.prev = NIL
    else
        L.tail = NIL
    return x
```

Also, you don't really need a double-linked list. A single-linked list should work just fine (unless you want to also support other operations).

Answer (score 0):

There are two standard implementations of a queue.

A ring buffer can be stored in an array, with pointers to the head and tail. All arithmetic is done modulo the length of the array. If the tail catches up to the head, the queue has overflowed and can no longer be used.

Another implementation uses two linked lists. The first list is the front of the queue, in order; the second list is the back of the queue, in reverse order. Items are added to the second list and retrieved from the first list. Any time the first list is empty and an item is to be fetched, the second list is reversed and becomes the first list, and a new (empty) second list is created.

Both implementations have time complexity O(1) to insert and fetch/delete. The ring buffer implementation has absolute time complexity O(1) but predefines the maximum size of the queue. The linked lists implementation has amortized time complexity O(1) but no limit on the maximum size of the queue, assuming sufficient memory is available.